'apt-get update' failing
So i just now tried to update my installed packages in order to upgrade my Debian version and 'apt-get update -y' threw me this error:
apt-get update -y
Hit:1 http://security.debian.org buster/updates InRelease
Hit:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease
Hit:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease
Ign:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports InRelease
Err:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 199.232.150.132 80]
Get:6 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian buster InRelease [53.9 kB]
Get:7 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_12.x buster InRelease [4,584 B]
Get:8 https://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian stable-buster InRelease [5,874 B]
Get:9 https://packages.microsoft.com/debian/10/prod buster InRelease [6,538 B]
Ign:10 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt kubernetes-xenial InRelease
Err:12 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt kubernetes-xenial Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 216.58.214.174 443]
Get:11 https://adoptopenjdk.jfrog.io/adoptopenjdk/deb buster InRelease [11.5 kB]
Err:11 https://adoptopenjdk.jfrog.io/adoptopenjdk/deb buster InRelease
  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
Hit:13 https://packagecloud.io/ookla/speedtest-cli/debian buster InRelease
Get:14 https://packages.microsoft.com/debian/10/prod buster/main amd64 Packages [223 kB]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'https://apt.kubernetes.io kubernetes-xenial Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch https://adoptopenjdk.jfrog.io/adoptopenjdk/deb/dists/buster/InRelease  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
E: The repository 'https://adoptopenjdk.jfrog.io/adoptopenjdk/deb buster InRelease' is no longer signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

Is there any way to fix this mess without reinstalling the server?

Debian 10 ("buster") is no longer supported except as for its Long Term Support (LTS) variant, which runs until June 2024, i.e. just a few weeks away.
The backports repository for Debian 10 no longer exists, as there is no need to backport packages, and other third-party package repositories that target "buster" also no longer exist.
You should take a backup and then upgrade through Debian 11 ("bullseye") to Debian 12 ("bookworm"). Or build out a fresh system running Debian 12 ("bookworm") and migrate your applications and data. Do not attempt to upgrade directly from Debian 10 ("buster") to Debian 12 ("bookworm").
Some suggestions to ease any potential upgrade:

Take a backup (and check it restores)
Remove all third party package repositories
Remove references to buster-backports
Have a read of Debian's OldOldStable page
Read the upgrade notes for "bullseye" before attempting it
Perform the first ugprade within the next month so as to avoid crashing against the 30 June deadline
Read the ugprade notes for "bookworm" before attempting it


I have upgraded about 10 different machines with this recipe:

Replace from /etc/apt/sources.list buster/updates with bullseye-securityand then all occurances of buster with bullseye.
Update the package listing: apt update
Minimal system upgrade: apt upgrade --without-new-pkgs
Last step: apt full-upgrade

